Getting error while connecting to multiple databases in one single application
I am developing an application that connects to multiple databases. Each request triggers a job designed to connect to a specific database. This job will then execute a series of queries. Currently, the system can handle up to five simultaneous jobs.
The issue arises when a second request is received; the first job then encounters the following error:
No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found.
The database connection in each job is established as follows:
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: 'mysql2',
      encoding: 'utf8mb4',
      collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      reconnect: true,
      pool: 5,
      database: db_database,
      username: db_username,
      password: db_password,
      host: db_host
    )

Is there any way to solve this?

Are those different databases in different mysql instances or are they in the same instance? If the former, then one connection is enough, just use db_name.table_name syntax instead of table_name

They are different instances, with different hosts and different users. The problem is that when making a connection to another database, it disconnects the ones from other jobs that are running

You must have different connection pools for each of the instances.

Sorry, how can that be done?

I'm sorry, I only know mysql and this is not a mysql question any more.

Is each job based on the same class or are their 5 individual classes?
